# Content quickly disappears

Tags: android

Working on building my first android app, and I have a simple button that should get the location of the user(and save it in a DB). When I click this, the page I want to load does but it quickly disappears after the information is saved in the DB. I'm sure this is something simple, but for the life of me I can't get the new activity to stay put. The basic question is how do I get the textview with ACTIVE to stay on screen after the button is clicked from the first bit of code below.

Here is the button in the java class to start the activity:

```
public class WalkerMain extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
    private Button mActive;
    public String user = null;
    public Integer user_id = 0;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.walker_app);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

        if (extras != null) {
            user = extras.getString("user");
            user_id = extras.getInt("user_id");
            Log.d("In WalkerMain!", user);
        }
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        if (toolbar != null) {
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        }
        mActive = (Button) findViewById(R.id.go_active);
        // register listeners
        mActive.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i = new Intent(this, WalkerActive.class);
                i.putExtra("user", user);
                i.putExtra("user_id", user_id);
                startActivity(i);

        }
    }
```

And the activity that updates the user information and should just display a simple textbox on the contentview.

```
public class WalkerActive extends ActionBarActivity implements
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener
{

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    //ids
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";
    public Double lat, lon;
    public Integer radius = 0;
    public String user = null;
    public Integer user_id = null;
    public JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    private static final String UPDATE_URL = "...";
    private final String TAG = "APP";

    private TextView mLocationView;

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.walker_active);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        if (toolbar != null) {
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        }

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // Connect the client.
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        // Disconnecting the client invalidates it.
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        // Display the connection status
        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        List<String> providers = lm.getProviders(true);

        /* Loop over the array backwards, and if you get an accurate location, then break out the loop*/
        Location l = null;

        for (int i=providers.size()-1; i>=0; i--) {
            l = lm.getLastKnownLocation(providers.get(i));
            if (l != null) break;
        }

        if (l != null) {
            lat = l.getLatitude();
            lon = l.getLongitude();
        }
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            user = extras.getString("user");
            user_id = extras.getInt("user_id");
            Log.d("In WalkerActive", user);
        }
        String ret_value = null;
        try {
            ret_value = new UpdateActive().execute().get();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection has been suspend");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection has failed");
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        mLocationView.setText("Location received: " + location.toString());
    }



    class UpdateActive extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(WalkerActive.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Going Active...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // Check for success tag
            int success;
            try {
                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_id", user_id.toString()));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("radius", radius.toString()));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lat", lat.toString()));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lon",lon.toString()));
                Log.d("request!", "starting");
                Log.d("params",params.toString());
                JSONObject json_update = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                        UPDATE_URL, "POST", params);
                //Log.d("completed",json.toString());
                // full json_update response
                Log.d("Updated Activity", json_update.toString());

                // json_update success element
                success = json_update.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1) {
                    Log.d("Updated Activity!", json_update.toString());
                    finish();
                    return json_update.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                }else{
                    Log.d("Registering Failure!", json_update.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                    return json_update.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;

        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
            pDialog.dismiss();

        }

    }
}
```

walker_active.xml is very simple

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="ACTIVE"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

oka after looking at your code you got the

```
if (success == 1) {
                    Log.d("Updated Activity!", json_update.toString());
                    finish();
                    return json_update.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                }
```

in this if statement what `finish();` does is that this code is running in background so the Finish();statement simply stops ur current running function and stop the view .
try removing the Finish(); statement